# how can i code so that when i click on button in p5.js everytime it runs?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

is there any way so that whenever I click on the button it must run continuously.I have to refresh it every time in order to run it every time .
one more thing is there anyway to add list in the buttons like when i click on the button it must show me more options or i have to create different buttons everytime to show it like a menu

```js
var playAnim=false;
var img1
let posX=0
let posY=0
let button;
const rightwall=350;
function preload(){
  img1=loadImage("slag.jpg")
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  button =createButton('CLICK ME');
  button.position(250,300);
  button.mousePressed(changeBG);
  noLoop()
}

  function changeBG() {
  let val = random(255);
  background(val);
  loop();
  playAnim=true;
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill('red');
  rect(320,75,170,160)
  fill('grey');
  rect(posX,170,70,30)
  img=image(img1,posX,posY-280,180,200)
  
  posX=constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
  posY=constrain(posX-1,posY,height-20)
  
}
```

i want to know how can i code or what code can i add so that whenever  i click on the button it runs evertime.it must not stop or i dont have to refresh it every time

Comment: no .it doesn't all the two are different

Comment: the question scenario is different.here i am writing a code to know whenever i click the Button it must give the output but in the above code it runs only once irrespective of clicking me the number of times the button.   My question is the button runs only once but i want whenever i click the button it must start from the starting process

Answer (score 1):

Reset the coordinates `posX` and `posY` when the animation ends:

```js
posX = constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
posY = constrain(posX-1,posY,height-20)
if (posX == rightwall-30) {
    posX=0
    posY=0
}
```

Toggle the animation when the button is clicked:

```js
function changeBG() {
    let val = random(255);
    background(val);
    if (playAnim) {
        noLoop();
        playAnim = false;
    } else {
        loop();
        playAnim = true;
        posX=0
        posY=0
    }
}
```

```js
var playAnim=false;
var img1
let posX=0
let posY=0
let button;
const rightwall=350;

function preload(){
    img1=loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/master/resource/icon/Bird64.png")
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    button =createButton('CLICK ME');
    button.position(250,300);
    button.mousePressed(changeBG);
    noLoop()
}

function changeBG() {
    let val = random(255);
    background(val);
    if (playAnim) {
        noLoop();
        playAnim = false;
    } else {
        loop();
        playAnim = true;
        posX=0
        posY=0
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    fill('red');
    rect(320,75,170,160)
    fill('grey');
    rect(posX,170,70,30)
    
    image(img1,posX,posY-280,180,200)
    
    posX = constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
    posY = constrain(posX-1,posY,height-20)
    if (posX == rightwall-30) {
        posX=0
        posY=0
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, you can make the animation dependent on `playAnim`:

```js
function changeBG() {
    let val = random(255);
    background(val);
    playAnim = !playAnim;
    if (playAnim) {
        posX=0
        posY=0
    }
}
```

```js
if (playAnim) {
    posX = constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
    posY = constrain(posX-1,posY,height-20)
    if (posX == rightwall-30) {
        posX=0
        posY=0
    }
}
```

```js
var playAnim=false;
var img1
let posX=0
let posY=0
let button;
const rightwall=350;

function preload(){
    img1=loadImage("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/master/resource/icon/Bird64.png")
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    button =createButton('CLICK ME');
    button.position(250,300);
    button.mousePressed(changeBG);
}

function changeBG() {
    let val = random(255);
    background(val);
    playAnim = !playAnim;
    if (playAnim) {
        posX=0
        posY=0
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    fill('red');
    rect(320,75,170,160)
    fill('grey');
    rect(posX,170,70,30)
    
    image(img1,posX,posY-280,180,200)
    
    if (playAnim) {
        posX = constrain(posX+1,0,rightwall-30)
        posY = constrain(posX-1,posY,height-20)
        if (posX == rightwall-30) {
            posX=0
            posY=0
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ChandanKumarChowdhury Just set `posX=0` and `posY=0` when the button is clicked.